# Docker コンテナ内での Cassandra の起動

Tags: docker, cassandra

次の手順で Cassandra のインストールをしました。

```
(コンテナ内で Bash を起動)
$ docker run -ti centos:7 /bin/bash

(Cassandra のインストールのための yum リポジトリを登録)
# cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/datastax.repo
[datastax]
name = DataStax Repo for Apache Cassandra
baseurl = http://rpm.datastax.com/community
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 0

(Cassandra のインストール)
# yum install initscripts java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel cassandra22-tools -y
```

ところが、起動しようとすると `su: cannot open session: Permission denied` とのログが出力されます。

```
(Cassandra の起動 - きちんと起動しているように見える)
# service cassandra start
Starting Cassandra: OK

(ところが Cassandra プロセスは起動していない)
# ps aux | grep java
root       190  0.0  0.0   9040   816 ?        S+   08:08   0:00 grep --color=auto java

(ログには Permission denied とある)
# cat /var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log
su: cannot open session: Permission denied
```

どうやら、起動スクリプト内で Cassandra ユーザーになろうとして失敗しているようです。

```
# su - cassandra
su: cannot open session: Permission denied
```

この問題はどのように修正すればよいでしょうか? `/etc/init.d/cassandra` で強制的に Cassandra を `root` で立ち上げるようにすれば起動するのですが、筋が良くないように思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf で cassandra ユーザーのリソース(ulimit)を設定しているのですが、docker コンテナ内では memlock の値を上げることができないようです。

```
(su に失敗)
[root]# cat /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf
cassandra - memlock unlimited
cassandra - nofile 100000
cassandra - nproc 32768
cassandra - as unlimited
[root]# su - cassandra -c /bin/whoami
su: cannot open session: Permission denied

(memlock を設定しないと su できる)
[root]# cat /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf
cassandra - nofile 100000
cassandra - nproc 32768
cassandra - as unlimited
[root]# su - cassandra -c /bin/whoami
cassandra
```

docker run の "--ulimit" オプションで上限を引き上げることができそうです。

```
docker run -ti --ulimit memlock=-1 centos:7 /bin/bash
※"memlock=unlimited" はエラーとなります。"-1" で設定できるようです。
```

ちなみに、"session" は Linux PAM の session のことだと思います(説明省略、検索してください)。
/etc/pam.d/su の session 設定 → /etc/pam.d/system-auth の session 設定 → pam_limits.so → /etc/security/{limits.conf,limits.d/*}

Comment: `memlock` の設定を消すことで Cassandra ユーザーでの起動に成功しました!

まさに `session` とは何だろうと疑問に思っていたので、そちらも併せてありがとうございました!